# OS X Web View App - Is it possible to use the native Preferences panel to adjust JavaScript variables?

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I wrote an app in HTML5/JavaScript and embedded it as an OS X web view. It works and currently has a settings area built into the web app which also works.

My question is, is it possible to use a native OS X style preferences panel (App Name > Preferences) to adjust the settings of the web app?

The web app uses JavaScript variables for the settings. The OS X preferences panel would have to read the JavaScript variables, allow them to be adjusted, and then update them upon save.

Example web code (test.html):

```
<p>Number of widgets (sample setting): 
<input type="button" id="buttonLessWidgets" value="&lt;">
<span id="divNumWidgets"></span>
<input type="button" id="buttonMoreWidgets" value="&gt;">
</p>

<script>
var numWidgets = 10;

// Display current number of widgets when the app is opened
document.getElementById("divNumWidgets").innerHTML = numWidgets;

// Adjust sample setting --- this is the part I'm hoping to move to the preferences panel
buttonLessWidgets.onclick = function() { 
    numWidgets -= 1;

    divNumWidgets.innerHTML = numWidgets;
};

buttonMoreWidgets.onclick = function() { 
    numWidgets += 1;

    divNumWidgets.innerHTML = numWidgets;
};
</script>
```

Is this something that I could easily implement? I'm comfortable with HTML5 and JavaScript but I am new to Xcode.

Comment: NSUserDefaults provides an easy way to persist settings like this, and you can use Cocoa Bindings with the shared user defaults controller to build the user interface with relative ease. I'm unclear about how you intend to get the values to your web view, though. How are you currently loading the JavaScript from your web view?

Answer (score 1):

It is very *possible*, but it'd require some work on your end, and there's no automatic way to do it. As for implementing a custom preferences pane, that's outside the scope of a single question, and you can probably find materials elsewhere. However, the actual JavaScript part isn't too bad.

The WebView class provides a `windowScriptObject` method which you can call to obtain a reference to the JavaScript environment. You can then use the standard `setValue:forKey:` and `valueForKey:` methods to get and set global variables in the JavaScript context.

You can inject these values into your page before it's actually loaded by providing a custom WebFrameLoadDelegate to the web view's `setFrameLoadDelegate:` method, and then utilizing the WebScriptObject context passed to the [`webView:didClearWindowObject:forFrame:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView%3adidClearWindowObject%3aforFrame%3a) delegate method. This method will be called as soon as the JavaScript context is available, but before the page actually loads, to allow you to insert your custom preference variables.